# react call custom hook inside hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that needs to be called inside another hook...

```
  const cancelButtonOnPressRef = useRef(() => {
    // any ideas?        
    useShowCancelMenu();
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you downvoted, please indicate the obvious reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const useNameYourCustomHook = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useShowCancelMenu(ref);
};
```